# How to check if there's a duplicate key row value in python and select the row which has Maximum Numeric column value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, duplicates, data-processing

I have the following data set:

[image]

I need to drop the rows which has duplicate Key value and keep only single Row value in data frame which has maximum Age.

Following is the output required:

[image]

I hope the problem statement is well defined.

Comment: Please post your data directly into your posts rather than using images for easier reproduction ;).

Comment: Okay  @Chris I'll keep this thing in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is dependent of which framework you use for your data.

If you use list of lists:

```
new_list = []
keys = set()
for row in old_list:
    key= row[0]
    if key in keys: # Allow no duplicates in set
        continue
    new_list.append(row)
```

If you use pandas for example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Key': ['AnaSay', 'Noolla', 'SamHus', 'SamHus', 'SamHus', 'SamHus', 'EliFer'],
    'Name': ['Ana', 'Noo', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Eli'],
    'Sir Name': ['Say', 'Ila', 'Hus', 'Hus', 'Hus', 'Hus', 'Fer'],
    'Age': [22, 25, 28, 30, 21, 20, 33],
    'Index': [1, 2, 5, 10, 12, 6, 2],
    'Max': [1, 2, 5, 10, 12, 6, 2],
    'T/F(Index==Max)': ['TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort_values(by=['Age']) # Sort dataframe by age
print(df)
print()
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Key', keep='last') # Save maximum age
print(df)
```

Comment: I did not get this @ErikXIII

Comment: Explain how you tables are represented/created then I can edit the answer to help you.

Comment: how keep='first' will help?

Comment: It means that the first occurrence is removed. Default is 'first' so not needed. If you wanted the last entry to be valid you could instead enter 'last'.

Comment: I dont want first or Last I want the max

Comment: Added a sorting of the dataframe by a column. Notice how 'first' changed to 'last'.

Answer (score 1):

In `pandas` you can do the following, with the advantage that you keep additional entries in case of a tie in the age:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{"key": 1, "name": "a", "age": 20},
                   {"key": 1, "name": "a", "age": 21},
                   {"key": 2, "name": "b", "age": 20}])


df.merge(df.groupby("key").age.max(), 
         left_on=("key", "age"), 
         right_on=("key", "age"))
```

Output:

```
    key     name    age
0   1   a   21
1   2   b   20
```

Comment: I tried this
pd.merge(df.groupby("key").age.max(), 
         left_on=("key", "age"), 
         right_on=("key", "age"))
Getting the following error:
merge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'right'

Comment: it's `df.merge` instead of `pd.merge`. also adjust the column names to capital key (e.g. `"Key"`) if using capital-cased columns.

Comment: Not working
showing foloowing value error:
can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: works on pandas 1.0.5. If it fails for you, you could also try `df.groupby("key").age.max().reset_index()` to turn the `Series` back into a `DataFrame`.